# WSO2 EMM Android Client: Device Information & Application List not updated

Tags: wso2-iot

I enrolled an Android Device (Ruggear RG700 Android 4.1.2).
After registering, the Device Information (battery, free RAM, free space) and the Application list shows information.
But after this first data set, there are never updates. Of course I tried to refresh the data by clicking the "refresh" icons. The other commands (e.g. camera, message) are working fine.

Is this a general bug or is this concerning just me?
Thanks in advance for any reply.
Conrad